# Spark-Submit CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a very simple spark code which is written using Python. I try to run this code in an standalone cluster.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":

    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("deneme").setMaster("spark://spark-master:7077")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    distData = sc.parallelize(data)
    distData.foreach(print)
```

I run the code following command:

```
spark-submit --master://spark-master:7077 abc.py
```

It is shown the results in stderr page in worker node. Also It shows an error in stderr page.

```
ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
```

I know it is very simple example but I can not find any solution.